# Need Android tabhost back press navigation

Tags: android

Friend's,
     I implemented tabhost in my application,i have three tabs defined in my activity tab1,tab2,tab3...here i have a problem to navigate from tab3 to tab1 at onkey back pressed event ,how can i reach the tab1 from tab3 and tab2,i tried up using overided keyback pressed,but it some times it's not responding to navigate.without overriding onkey back pressed it simply exits from application.

Here my code

```
tabHost= getTabHost();

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setContent(
                new Intent(this, DealCities.class)).setIndicator(prepareTabView("Deals",R.drawable.test)));

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setContent(new Intent(this, DbServerActivity.class))
                        .setIndicator(prepareTabView("My QuadDeals",R.drawable.mydeal)));

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setContent(new Intent(this, Account.class))
                .setIndicator(prepareTabView("My Account",R.drawable.img_myaccount)));
```

here the tabhost defined in one class and the tabhost object being static one,

here the code from my tab2 back pressed event  has follows,

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {

            try {               
//              userdealList.setVisibility(View.GONE);              
//              logalertTable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//              dealType.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//              mydealBack=1;
//              QuadMain.tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);  
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(DbServerActivity.this, QuadMain.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

it works fine sometimes only and sometimes it's not working..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what code do you have in your onBackPressed method?

Comment: have a look at my question once again i posted my code...event i tried to setCurrentTab() index also it remains the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this manual http://knightswhocode.com/wordpress/?p=46 - teaches how to use TabHost. Unfortunately by default onkeyBackPressed event you just go to the previous activity and as you have one main tabhost activity it just quits. I suggest you overriding the back key pressed and use the following method:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        YourParentActivity parentActivity;
        parentActivity = (YourParentActivity) this.getParent();
        parentActivity.switchTab(indexTabToSwitchTo);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
}
```

Comment: can please give  me detail for the above code,what the ParentActivity and MinTrack here

Comment: This is a way to get your parent activity. You should put your TabActivity name instead of MintTrack.

Comment: This is a name of a class where you have tabHost= getTabHost();

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setContent(
                new Intent(this, DealCities.class)).setIndicator(prepareTabView("Deals",R.drawable.test))); this code.

Answer (score 2):

Don't handle `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` in your tab activitys, do it in your main TabActivity.

As long as your tab activitys `onKeyDown()` methods don't handle it but they do call `super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);` it will filter up to your TabActivity.

In your TabActivity have a member `int currentTab = 0` then in the TabActivity do this...

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (currentTab == 0)
            currentTab = 2;
        else
            currentTab--;
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(currentTab);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
}
```